# AWS Redshift driver in Zeppelin

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, apache-zeppelin

I want to explore my data in Redshift using notebook Zeppelin. A small EMR cluster with Spark is running behind. I am loading databricks' spark-redshift library

```
%dep
z.reset()
z.load("com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:0.6.0")
```

and then

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val query = "..."

val url = "..."
val port=5439
val table = "..."
val database = "..."
val user = "..."
val password = "..."

val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
  .option("url", s"jdbc:redshift://${url}:$port/$database?user=$user&password=$password")
  .option("query",query)
  .option("tempdir", "s3n://.../tmp/data")
  .load()

df.show
```

but I get the error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load an Amazon Redshift JDBC driver; see the README for instructions on downloading and configuring the official Amazon driver
```

I added option

```
option("jdbcdriver", "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver")
```

but not for the better. I think I need to specify redshift's JDBC driver somewhere like I would passing --driver-class-path to spark-shell, but how to do that with zeppelin?

Comment: Given the error message, it looks like you need to do some extra configuration. Have you actually followed the instructions from that `README`? This is not a generic error message, but one produced by the redshift JDBC driver; so you have it installed, but it is just missing some configuration (or additional libraries?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add external jars with dependencies like the JDBC driver using either Zeppelin's [dependency-loading mechanism](http://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT/manual/dependencymanagement.html) or, in case of Spark, using `%dep` [dynamic dependency loader](http://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT/interpreter/spark.html)

> When your code requires external library, instead of doing download/copy/restart Zeppelin, you can easily do following jobs using %dep interpreter.
>
> - Load libraries recursively from Maven repository
> - Load libraries from local filesystem
> - Add additional maven repository
> - Automatically add libraries to SparkCluster (You can turn off)

The latter would look something like:

```
%dep
// loads with all transitive dependencies from Maven repo
z.load("groupId:artifactId:version")

// or add artifact from filesystem
z.load("/path/to.jar")
```

and by convention have to be in the first paragraph of the note.